# How to fix ShellItemRenderer and TabbedPageRenderer is not abstract error in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm migrating my Xamarin forms code to .NET MAUI. After migration when I build my Android project I get the following errors:

```
JAVAC0000 error: ShellItemRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) in OnItemSelectedListener

JAVAC0000 error: TabbedPageRenderer is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem) in OnItemSelectedListener
```

I tried updating **Xamarin.Google.Android.Material** to **1.8.0** but still it didn't solve for me. I got the following error, when adding the **NuGet-package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources**. If I don't add Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources package I will get following error:

```
Error XAGJS7028 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources,  Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

So this both errors are interconnected. I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or post [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have edited the question.

Comment: `I got the following error, when adding the NuGet-package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.Resources. `   What is the specific problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I think the error is occurring because of package. There is no specific way to reproduce it. For more info you can check this Github issue
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14492

Comment: I have also edited the question for better understanding.

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint the problem based on the error log you provide alone. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?